# PHP Column not found in a different query

Tags: php, mysql

I've a script in PHP to store data in a database. The script is called functions.php, this is its content:

```
class LoginRegister{
  function __construct($db){
    $this->db= $db;
}

public function regEventoPreesc($evento1,$desc1,$evento2,$desc2){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO 001_preesc(dia,descripcion) VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?)");
    $query->execute(array($evento1,$desc1,$evento2,$desc2));
    return true;
}

public function regEventoPrim($evento1,$desc1,$evento2,$desc2){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO 002_prim(dia,descripcion) VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?)");
    $query->execute(array($evento1,$desc1,$evento2,$desc2));
    return true;
}

public function regEventoSecu($evento1,$desc1,$evento2,$desc2){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO 003_secu(dia,descripcion) VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?)");
    $query->execute(array($evento1,$desc1,$evento2,$desc2));
    return true;
}

public function regMes($mes){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO mes(mes) VALUES (?)");  //LINE 29
    $query->execute(array($mes));
    return true;
}
}
```

When I call regMes function, it stores the data correctly on de database, but when I call regEventoSecu, regEventoPrim and regEventePreesc functions through a html form I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dia' in 'field list'' in /home/noewebst/public_html/act_eventos/functions.php:29
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /home/noewebst/public_html/act_eventos/functions.php(29): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>
> ## 1 /home/noewebst/public_html/act_eventos/act_preesc.php(104): LoginRegister->regEventoPreesc('Example 1', 'Description 1', 'Example 2', 'Description 2')
>
> ## 2 {main}
>
> thrown in /home/noewebst/public_html/act_eventos/functions.php on line 29

This is the form to save data.

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once "functions.php";
$db = new DatabaseConnection();
$user = new LoginRegister($db->pdo);

$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$username = $_SESSION['uname'];

if(!$user->getSession()){
  header('Location: login.php');
  exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div class="form">
<?php
                    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
                        $evento1=$_POST['evento1'];
                        $desc1=$_POST['desc1'];
                        $evento2=$_POST['evento2'];
                        $desc2=$_POST['desc2'];

                        $register = $user->regEventoPreesc($evento1,$desc1,$evento2,$desc2);

                        if($register){
                            echo "Data succesfully saved";
                        }
                    }
?>




            <form action="" method="post" name="reg">
                <table>
                    <tr><td><input type="text" name="evento1" placeholder="Día y mes"></td> 
                        <td><input type="text" name="desc1" placeholder="Descripción"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="text" name="evento2" placeholder="Día y mes"></td> 
                        <td><input type="text" name="desc2" placeholder="Descripción"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Guardar" onclick="return(submitreg());"></td></tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            </div>
            <br><br><br>
        <a class="boton_personalizado" href="actualizar.php">Regresar</a><br><br><br>
    </body>
```

Comment: be sure your 003_secu  table contain really the dia column   ..

Comment: It looks like your tables are missing the dia column

Comment: The field in the databese was diia instead dia. Thank yoou guys